# Fullcalendar submit data after complete manipulation of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Well lemme make my case.I anticipate to have a user base of around 200k.Each user will have a personal **Fullcalendar library** whereby they will manage events and their personal schedules for the entire year **365 days**.My issue arises whereby i wanna make only **one request** to the server per user to insert and update the date and event values.But using **my knowledge on fullcalendar library currently** iam forced to make requests to the server each time a user changes/updates an event,that is approximately to **265 requests per user to the server(assuming the other 100 days)** this a total drag to the server.I was wondering if it is possible to allow the user to make all the event changes they intend to and only when they are satisfied,then my code will run allowing a **submit** ,updating and inserting hence i would have **retained the one request i intend to achive** ie  using a **submit button** or any other solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Japheth, you can easily create all the events @ client-side and when you/customer want to save all the data on a submit button, just call `.fullCalendar('clientEvents')` and you will get all events stored inside the fullCalendar memory.

Comment: thanks  A1rPun lemme try it out